# how to insert custom customers attributes in orders and emails

Tags: attributes, orders, magento2.3, customer, email

I have successfully created custom customer attributes in Magento 2.3.2 (like doctor name and doctor zipcode) and I can see/modify them in my adminhtml customer view. What I would like is to have them inserted into customer orders and order e-mails. Has anyone already done that ?
Thank you for your pointers/hints/solutions !
Edit :

I tried using observers :
1 for customer signup, 1 on successful order.
So I added 2 modules

**One called CustomerRegister : registration.php :**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CustomerRegister_Emails',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
<observer name="customerregister" instance="CustomerRegister\Emails\Observer\AddCustomerData">
    </event>
</config>
```

etc/module.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CustomerRegister" setup_version="1.0.1">
<sequence>
<module name="Magento_CustomerRegister"/>
</sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Observer/AddCustomerData.php :

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Emails\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomerData implements ObserverInterface
{
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
  ){
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($transport->getOrder()->GetCustomerId());

$transport->addData([
'nommedecin' => $customer->getCustomAttribute('nommedecin')->getValue()

]);
}
}
```

If I insert the `{{ var nommedecin }}` in my new customer email template, it's empty... 
If you have any clues, please do not hesitate